# How to calculate slope and distance of two vectors in r?

Tags: r, difference

I want to calculate slope and distance of two vectors. I am using the following code

```
df = structure(list(x = c(92.2, 88.1, 95.8, 83.8, 76.7, 83.3, 101.1, 
111.8, 84.3, 81.5, 76.2, 87.1), y = c(84.8, 78.5, 103.1, 90.4, 
85.1, 78.2, 98.3, 109.2, 85.6, 86.9, 85.6, 94)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-12L))

x <- df$x
y <- df$y

#Slope
diff(y)/diff(x)

#Distance
dist(df, method = "euclidean")
```

You can see in the output of slope that 11 values are coming. I want to have the slope of 12-1 also. How can I get that? and the from distance output I only want the values of 1-2, 2-3, 3-4, 4-5, 5-6, 6-7, 7-8, 8-9, 9-10, 10-11, 11-12 and 12-1 combinations. How can I achieve it?
The expected output is

```
Length 7.5 25.8 17.5 8.9 9.5 26.8 15.3 36.2 3.1 5.5 13.8 10.5
Slope 1.54 3.19 1.06 0.75 -1.05 1.13 1.02 0.86 -0.46 0.25 0.77 1.08
```

Comment: There's no nice `diff` function for getting the difference of the last and first vector elements, you can directly use `(y[12] - y[1]) / (x[12] - x[1])`, or if you want to be more general use `tail(x, 1)` for the last element and `head(x, 1)` for the first element.

Comment: Try creating a new df by adding the first row at the end, i.e. `df1 <- rbind(df, df[1,])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the `diff` [approach by @Gregor Thomas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70170592/12158757) is concise enough. Here is another option in case you are interested in `dist` for computing diatances.

```
> d <- rbind(df, df[1, ])

> with(d, diff(y) / diff(x))
 [1]  1.5365854  3.1948052  1.0583333  0.7464789 -1.0454545  1.1292135
 [7]  1.0186916  0.8581818 -0.4642857  0.2452830  0.7706422 -1.8039216

> (m <- as.matrix(dist(d)))[col(m) - row(m) == 1]
 [1]  7.516648 25.776928 17.472550  8.860023  9.548298 26.848650 15.274161
 [8] 36.238239  3.087070  5.457105 13.761177 10.519030
```

Comment: Good for small data, but calculating the whole distance matrix when you only need the off-diagonal will feel very expensive on even medium-sized data.

Comment: Appending the first point to the end is quite nice, though!

Comment: @GregorThomas yes, I agree that my approach doesn't work well for large vectors. and that's why I think yours is better :)

Answer (score 2):

There's no nice `diff` function for getting the difference of the last and first vector elements, you can directly use `(y[12] - y[1]) / (x[12] - x[1])`, or if you want to be more general use `tail(x, 1)` for the last element and `head(x, 1)` for the first element. Calculate it directly and append it to your `slope` vector.

For euclidean distance, of successive points, its most direct to calculate it directly: `distance = sqrt(diff(x)^2 + diff(y)^2)`.

```
(slope = c(diff(y)/diff(x), (head(y, 1) - tail(y, 1)) / (head(x, 1) - tail(x, 1))))
# [1]  1.5365854  3.1948052  1.0583333  0.7464789 -1.0454545  1.1292135  1.0186916
# [8]  0.8581818 -0.4642857  0.2452830  0.7706422 1.8039216

(distance = sqrt(diff(x)^2 + diff(y)^2))
# [1]  7.516648 25.776928 17.472550  8.860023  9.548298 26.848650 15.274161 36.238239  3.087070  5.457105 13.761177
```

I'll leave it as an exercise for the reader to add the last `distance` between the first and last points.

Comment: Can you show the outputs from your code? I have provided the expected output in my question.

Comment: @BappaDas See edits.

Comment: Nice answer! upvoted!